# Django port not open in container when starting Django Docker container via shell script

Tags: django, bash, docker

I'm trying to containerize my Django application, and everything is working fine, except in the situation where I try to run the container from a shell script. In this case, the Django server is running, but the port is not open inside the container.

Here's the command I'm running to start the container:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --net=mynet --name myapp -v $PWD:/myapp myimage ./ss
```

`ss` is a shell script that launches my Django app. It contains:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

When I run the Docker RUN command from the command line, everything works fine; the port is mapped correctly, I can browse to my app from a browser in my host and it loads correctly, etc.

However, if I copy the above run command in a shell script (start_container.sh for example), the container launches just fine, the ports are mapped correctly, but when I try to open the app in my browser, I get a connection reset error.

If open a shell to the container by running

```
docker exec -i -t myapp /bin/bash
```

I can get into the container. I check running processes with `ps -eaf` I do see the python process running my Django app. However, if I check open ports from within the container with `netstat -a` or `netstat -l`, port 8000 is **NOT** available.

If I then stop the container, then restart it from the command line, and inspect the container, `netstat -a` will show port 8000 as available, and I can connect to my app from a host browser.

I'm a bit at a loss to explain how launching the docker container from the host would have this impact on the container internally, and I'm not sure what my next debugging steps should be.

Note 1: When inside the container, if I run the start script `./ss`, Django starts and the port opens as expected.

Note 2: I also tried using the CMD ["ss"] instruction in my container's Dockerfile, and I get the same result; if I launch the container from the commandline, it works fine. If I launch it from a shell script, the port inside the container doesn't open.

Comment: What are the permissions on the script? Maybe isn't executable

Comment: Please at the add the output of `ps aux` and `netstat -plant` when the issue happens